# Alternative for nested activityForResult?

Tags: android

In my main activity, when you click a button, normally it bundles some info and startActivityForResult another activity (act2). Then in onActivityResult, depending on the resultCode, I do something.

Now I need to add a license check between there. Main activity, click button, check license, if ok bring up act2. Now, I bundle some data, startActivityForResult, use that bundle data in my license check to startActivityForResult act2. Once act2 finishes, it goes into onActivityResult in my license check, which then sets result and finishes, finally going back to my main activity.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you do the check license in the onClickListener of the Button itself and then call act2 if everything is ok.

Comment: I don't know what Roger's reasons are, but one reason would be to stop other apps launching a licensed activity directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Create a subclass of Activity, say LicensedActivity. Put all the license checking in onCreate(), and call finish() if the check fails.
2. Make act2 as subclass of LicensedActivity

Do you really need to check the license both before and after calling act2?